# Provide function pointers access to private members of C++ class- is it possible?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, private-members

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

-Client registers a function (fun) with the class (foo)

-Fun has a general form type function(int, int,int)

-Foo then, in executing its work, calls that function *which may require access to private members*.

The point is to allow user defined functions which Foo can use in the course of its work. Is there a pattern/nuance of C++ etc.. that would make this feasible?

Worst case scenario I can make the data public but I'm curious if something better exists.

TIA

Example:

```
class foo;

typedef float (*client_fun)(foo &obj, int &i);
class foo
{
   client_fun their_fun;

   int private_info;

 public:
   foo(): private_info(42){};

   void set_fun(client_fun _fun)
     {
        their_fun = _fun;
     }

   float run_foo()
     {
        //Oversimplified example of what it would be doing.
        //their_fun would be called as part of a complicated method
        int i;
        i = 1;
        return their_fun(*this, i);
     }

};

float fancy_fun(foo &obj, int &i)
{
   //needs access to private info
   return (i/obj.private_info);
}

int main()
{
   //Hypothetical use
   foo my_foo;

   my_foo.set_fun(fancy_fun);

   //Can't access the private member
   my_foo.run_foo();

   return 0;
}
```

G++ example.cpp:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘float fancy_fun(foo&, int&)’:
example.cpp:8:8: error: ‘int foo::private_info’ is private
    int private_info;
        ^
example.cpp:32:18: error: within this context
    return (i/obj.private_info);
```

Comment: Make the function a friend...? Am I missing something? Sounds like a broken design though if you need external functions to have internal access to a type. If the type has a public interface then the public interface should be public.

Comment: How does the function know about the private variables of the class?

Comment: Did you actually try this?  There's no obvious problem here.  Post the code that does not work.

Comment: Are you referring to some kind of _callback_ for e.g. dispatching events? Please clarify.

Comment: I added an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is right -- this is exactly the kind of situation `friend` is meant for.  It provides an explicit exception to the public/protected/private settings you have already chosen and that otherwise satisfy your design.

Comment: But is it possible to do so without redefining the friended function? The implementation has default functions it will call if not supplied user defined ones. I'd rather them not be literally overwriting the definition of the default method to implement their own.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoters would like to explain to a newb why it is you down voted the question? It is not a trivial problem in so far as I was asking for a pattern or a nuance which would help me achieve the specification which I address below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern that answers my question.

```
#include <iostream>

class engine;

class settings
{
   //Can friend the engine class if we have private members we want to be able to call
   friend class engine;

 public:
   int private_info;
   settings()

     {
        private_info = 42;
     };
};

typedef float (*fn_ptr)(settings &);

class engine
{
   //private info will still be private to the world since the engine owns the settings object
   settings my_settings;
   fn_ptr my_fn;

 public:

   engine(): my_settings(){};

   void set_fun(fn_ptr _ptr)
     {
        my_fn = _ptr;
     }

   void run()
     {
        std::cout << my_fn(my_settings, 1) << "\n";
     }
};


float fancy_fun(settings &obj, size_t i)
{
   //needs access to private info
   return (obj.private_info);
}

int main()
{
   //Hypothetical use
   engine my_engine;

   my_engine.set_fun(fancy_fun);


   //Error! Private!
   //my_engine.my_settings;

    /*Is now accessing the public member of a private object
    * using an appropriately specified user function */
   my_engine.run();

   return 0;
}
```